# Put all parents into list recursively

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have a Category object (fetched with EF) which has a navigational object Parent, which is basically another Category.

These Category objects keep recursing until Parent is null.

What I need to get:

```
<ul>
    <li>Highest level category (parent=null)</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Second highest level category</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Local category</li>
            </ul>
        <ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Preferably without a ton of string manipulation (because there's a ton of classes and other things involved), and purely with recursive views. Now the problem is, I have no idea how it should work. It would be easy if I went down from highest level category, but I need to go up instead (backwards).

What I have:

```
@model Domain.Category

@{
    ViewBag.Recursion = (int) ViewBag.Recursion + 1;
}

@if (Model.Parent != null)
{
    @Html.Partial("_RecursiveCategory", Model.Parent)
    <li>
        <ul class="categorylist">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(Model.Name, "Index", "Categories", new {Model.Id, name = Model.FriendlyName}, null)</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(Model.Name, "Index", "Categories", new {Model.Id, name = Model.FriendlyName}, null)</li>
}
```

Which obviously goes fine to second level but from there on out, they're all in the same line.

So, can anyone think of a nice solution on how to solve this? Again, without massive hacks of string concatenation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to tweak the ul/li's that are created, but here's the `View`:

```
@functions{


MvcHtmlString CreateTree(MvcApplication2.Models.Category  category)
{
    var swriter  = new StringWriter();
    var writer = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(swriter);

    CreateTree(category, writer);

    writer.Close();

    return new MvcHtmlString(swriter.ToString());
}

void CreateTree(MvcApplication2.Models.Category  category, System.Xml.XmlWriter outputWriter)
{
    if (category.Parent != null)
    {
        CreateTree(category.Parent, outputWriter);
    }

    // bubble up after recursion
    outputWriter.WriteStartElement("ul");
    outputWriter.WriteElementString("li", category.Title);
    outputWriter.WriteStartElement("li");
}  

}

    <div>

    @CreateTree(ViewBag.Category)


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try someThing like following:

```
private string GenerateUL(IQueryable<Menu> menus)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.AppendLine("<ul>");
    foreach (var menu in menus)
    {
        if (menu.Menus.Any())
        {
            sb.AppendLine("<li>" + menu.Text);
            sb.Append(GenerateUL(menu.Menus.AsQueryable()));
            sb.AppendLine("</li>");
        } 
        else
            sb.AppendLine("<li>" + menu.Text + "</li>");
        }
    }
    sb.AppendLine("</ul>");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

controller

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    return View(GenerateUL(Category.Children));
}
```

View

```
@model string

@{
    ViewBag.Recursion = (int) ViewBag.Recursion + 1;
}

@if (Model != null)
{
    @Html.Partial("_RecursiveCategory", Model.Parent)
    @Model
}
else
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(Model.Name, "Index", "Categories", new {Model.Id, name = Model.FriendlyName}, null)</li>
}
```